# How to get texture coordinates from VTK IntersectWithLine?

Tags: c++, vtk

I've loaded a texture mapped OBJ via `vtkOBJReader` and loaded it into a `vtkModifiedBSPTree`:

```
auto readerOther(vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJReader>::New());
auto rawOtherPath(modelPathOther.toLatin1());
readerOther->SetFileName(rawOtherPath.data());
readerOther->Update();

auto meshDataOther(readerOther->GetOutput());

auto bspTreeOther(vtkSmartPointer<vtkModifiedBSPTree>::New());
bspTreeOther->SetDataSet(meshDataOther);
bspTreeOther->BuildLocator();
```

I then compute my line segment start and end and feed that into

```
if (bspTreeOther->IntersectWithLine(p1, p2, tolerance, distanceAlongLine, intersectionCoords, pcoords, subId, cellId, cell))
```

With all the relevant predefined variables of course.

**What I need is the texture's UV coordinates at the point of intersection.**

I'm so very new to VTK that I've not yet caught the logic of how its put together yet; the abstraction layers are still losing me while I'm digging through the source.

I've hunted for this answer across SO and the VTK users archives and found vague hints given by those who understood VTK deeply to those who were nearly there themselves, and thus of little help to me thus far.

(Appended 11/9/2018)
To clarify, I'm working with non-degenerate triangulated meshes created by a single 3D scanner shot, so quads and other higher polygons are not going to be ever seen by my code.  A general solution should account for such things, but that can be accomplished via triangulating the mesh first via a good application of handwavium.

Comment: How do you define the "UV coordinates" ?

Comment: I think that that you wrapped a texture around some polygon in 3d space. So there was some deformation of initial texture bitmap. And you want to get a point of intesection of object and line, but you want it in coordinates of raw and column of initial bitmap of texture instead of 2-d coordinates from plane corresponding to flat polygon in 3d space. Have I understood everything correctly?

Comment: The UV coordinates are [defined in the OBJ file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Vertex_texture_coordinate_indices) as what OBJ calls "vertex texture coordinates" and are simply the XY location in an image using a 0.0 to 1.0 scale for each axis.  They allow for finding the corresponding point on the image for the given vertex. In this case I want that XY value as interpolated in the cell that was hit by the IntersectWithLine.

Comment: @VideoProcessingResearcher, pretty much, excepting that my 3d space object is composed of many polygons, triangles specifically, and is most definitely not a plane.  That said, yes, the vertices have been mapped to the texture and such info is in the OBJ as I just posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code

**Note** that if one vertex belongs to several polygons and has different texture coordinates, VTK will create duplicates of the vertex.
I don't use [vtkCleanPolyData](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCleanPolyData.html), because VTK will merge such "duplicates" and we will lose needed information, as far as I know.

I use [vtkCellLocator](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCellLocator.html) instead of [vtkModifiedBSPTree](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkModifiedBSPTree.html),
because in my case it was faster.

The main file `main.cpp`.
You can find magic numbers in `start` and `end` arrays — these are your `p1` and `p2`.
I've set these values just for example

```
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkPointData.h>
#include <vtkCellLocator.h>
#include <vtkGenericCell.h>
#include <vtkOBJReader.h>
#include <vtkTriangleFilter.h>
#include <vtkMath.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " OBJ_file_name" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto reader{vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJReader>::New()};
    reader->SetFileName(argv[1]);
    reader->Update();
    // Triangulate the mesh if needed
    auto triangleFilter{vtkSmartPointer<vtkTriangleFilter>::New()};
    triangleFilter->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
    triangleFilter->Update();
    auto mesh{triangleFilter->GetOutput()};
    // Use `auto mesh(reader->GetOutput());` instead if no triangulation needed

    // Build a locator to find intersections
    auto locator{vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellLocator>::New()};
    locator->SetDataSet(mesh);
    locator->BuildLocator();

    // Initialize variables needed for intersection calculation
    double start[3]{-1, 0, 0.5};
    double end[3]{   1, 0, 0.5};
    double tolerance{1E-6};
    double relativeDistanceAlongLine;
    double intersectionCoordinates[3];
    double parametricCoordinates[3];
    int subId;
    vtkIdType cellId;
    auto cell{vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericCell>::New()};
    // Find intersection
    int intersected = locator->IntersectWithLine(
        start,
        end,
        tolerance,
        relativeDistanceAlongLine,
        intersectionCoordinates,
        parametricCoordinates,
        subId,
        cellId,
        cell.Get()
    );

    // Get points of intersection cell
    auto pointsIds{vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList>::New()};
    mesh->GetCellPoints(cellId, pointsIds);
    // Store coordinates and texture coordinates of vertices of the cell
    double meshTrianglePoints[3][3];
    double textureTrianglePoints[3][2];
    auto textureCoordinates{mesh->GetPointData()->GetTCoords()};
    for (unsigned pointNumber = 0; pointNumber < cell->GetNumberOfPoints(); ++pointNumber)
    {
        mesh->GetPoint(pointsIds->GetId(pointNumber), meshTrianglePoints[pointNumber]);
        textureCoordinates->GetTuple(pointsIds->GetId(pointNumber), textureTrianglePoints[pointNumber]);
    }

    // Normalize the coordinates
    double movedMeshTrianglePoints[3][3];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        movedMeshTrianglePoints[0][i] = 0;
        movedMeshTrianglePoints[1][i] =
            meshTrianglePoints[1][i] -
            meshTrianglePoints[0][i];
        movedMeshTrianglePoints[2][i] =
            meshTrianglePoints[2][i] -
            meshTrianglePoints[0][i];
    }
    // Normalize the texture coordinates
    double movedTextureTrianglePoints[3][2];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        movedTextureTrianglePoints[0][i] = 0;
        movedTextureTrianglePoints[1][i] =
            textureTrianglePoints[1][i] -
            textureTrianglePoints[0][i];
        movedTextureTrianglePoints[2][i] =
            textureTrianglePoints[2][i] -
            textureTrianglePoints[0][i];
    }

    // Calculate SVD of a matrix consisting of normalized vertices
    double U[3][3];
    double w[3];
    double VT[3][3];
    vtkMath::SingularValueDecomposition3x3(movedMeshTrianglePoints, U, w, VT);
    // Calculate pseudo inverse of a matrix consisting of normalized vertices
    double pseudoInverse[3][3]{0};
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            for (unsigned k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
            {
                if (w[k] != 0)
                {
                    pseudoInverse[i][j] += VT[k][i] * U[j][k] / w[k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Calculate interpolation matrix
    double interpolationMatrix[3][2]{0};
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        {
            for (unsigned k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
            {
                interpolationMatrix[i][j] += pseudoInverse[i][k] * movedTextureTrianglePoints[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    // Calculate interpolated texture coordinates of the intersection point
    double interpolatedTexturePoint[2]{textureTrianglePoints[0][0], textureTrianglePoints[0][1]};
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            interpolatedTexturePoint[i] += (intersectionCoordinates[j] - meshTrianglePoints[0][j]) * interpolationMatrix[j][i];
        }
    }

    // Print the result
    std::cout << "Interpolated texture coordinates";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << " " << interpolatedTexturePoint[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

CMake project file `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

PROJECT(IntersectInterpolate)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(IntersectInterpolate MACOSX_BUNDLE main.cpp)

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
    target_link_libraries(IntersectInterpolate ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
    target_link_libraries(IntersectInterpolate vtkHybrid vtkWidgets)
endif()
```

## Math

### What we need

Suppose you have a mesh consisting of triangles and your vertices have texture coordinates.

Given vertices of a triangle `A`, `B` and `C`, corresponding texture coordinates `A'`, `B'` and `C'`, you want to find a mapping (to interpolate) from another inner and boundary points of the triangle to the texture.
Let's make some rational assumptions:

- Points `A`, `B`, `C` should correspond to their texture coordinates `A'`, `B'`, `C'`;
- Each point `X` on the border, say `AB`, should correspond to the points of `A'B'` line in following way: `|AX| / |AB| = |A'X'| / |A'B'|` — half way on the original triangle should be a half way on the texture map;

  - Centroid of the triangle `(A + B + C) / 3` should correspond to centroid of the texture triangle `(A' + B' + C') / 3`.

### Equations to solve

Looks like we want to have affine mapping: coordinates of vertices of the original triangle should be multiplied by some coefficients and be added to some constants.
Let's construct the system of equations

```
Ax * Mxx + Ay * Myx + Az * Mzx + M0x = A'x
Ax * Mxy + Ay * Myy + Az * Mzy + M0y = A'y
Ax * Mxz + Ay * Myz + Az * Mzz + M0z = 0
```

and the same for `B` and `C`.
You can see that we have `9` equations and `12` unknowns.
Though, equations containing `Miz` (for `i` in `{x, y, z}`) have the solution `0` and don't play any role in further computations, so we can just set them equal to `0`.
Thus, we have system with `6` equations and `8` unknowns

```
Ax * Mxx + Ay * Myx + Az * Mzx + M0x = A'x
Ax * Mxy + Ay * Myy + Az * Mzy + M0y = A'y
```

Let's write entire system in matrix view

```
--          --   --       --   --       --
| 1 Ax Ay Az |   | M0x M0y |   | A'x A'y |
| 1 Bx By Bz | x | Mxx Mxy | = | B'x B'y |
| 1 Cx Cy Cz |   | Myx Myy |   | C'x C'y |
--          --   | Mzx Mzy |   --       --
                 --       --
```

I subtract coordinates of `A` vertex from `B` and `C`
and texture coordinates `A'` from `B'` and `C'`,
and now we have the triangle with the first vertex located
in start of coordinate system as well as corresponding texture coordinates.
This means that now triangles are not translated (moved) one relative to another
and we don't need `M0` part of interpolation matrix

```
--        --   --       --   --       --
| Bx By Bz |   | Mxx Mxy |   | B'x B'y |
| Cx Cy Cz | x | Myx Myy | = | C'x C'y |
--        --   | Mzx Mzy |   --       --
               --       --
```

### Solution

Let's call the first matrix `P`, the second `M` and the last one `T`

```
P M = T
```

The matrix `P` is not square.
If we add zero row to it, the matrix becomes singular.
So, we have to calculate pseudo-inverse of it in order to solve the equation.
There's no function for calculating pseudo-inverse matrix in VTK.
We go to [Moore–Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Singular_value_decomposition_(SVD)) article on Wikipedia and see that it can be calculated using SVD.
[VTKMath::SingularValueDecomposition3x3](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkMath.html#a6129424c4b605945653e9c64c6868abc) function allows us to do it.
The function gives us `U`, `S` and `VT` matrices.
I'll write pseudo-inverse of matrix `P` as `P"`,
transposition of `U` as `UT` and transposition of `VT` as `V`.
Pseudo-inverse of diagonal matrix `S` is a matrix with `1 / Sii` elements
where `Sii` is not a zero and `0` for zero elements

```
P = U S VT
P" = V S" UT
M = P" T
```

### Usage

To apply interpolation matrix,
we need to not forget that we need to translate input and output vectors.
`A'` is a 2D vector of texture coordinates of the first vertex in the triangle,
`A` is a 3D vector of coordinates of the vertex,
`M` is the found interpolation matrix,
`p` is a 3D intersection point we want to get texture coordinates for,
`t'` is the resulting 2D vector with interpolated texture coordinates

```
t' = A' + (p - A) M
```

Comment: Thank you. My grasp of linear algebra has fallen out of use after being away from it for ~5 years.  Could you extend your excellent answer with some reference code, at least pseudocode?  That would make it far easier for me to comprehend. (And my apologies for not noticing this months earlier!)

Comment: Also, if you could incorporate the parts of my answer that were applicable to your solution so that the answer is complete this would be an excellent one-stop-shop for future visitors.

Comment: @RickyC, I guess the code is clear enough to modify it for your needs. I've tried it only on triangles, so I've removed a part about quads, but added triangulation. I guess, it's not crucial, because, if you don't need to edit the mesh, it should not be a problem to find intersection on triangulated one

Answer (score 1):

[Rewritten 2019/5/7 to reflect an updated understanding.]

After finding out that the parametric coordinates are inputs to a function from which one can get barycentric coordinates in the case of triangular cells, and then learning about what barycentric coordinates are, I was able to work out the following.

```cpp
    const auto readerOther(vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJReader>::New());
    const auto rawOtherPath(modelPathOther.toLatin1());
    readerOther->SetFileName(rawOtherPath.data());
    readerOther->Update();

    const auto meshDataOther(readerOther->GetOutput());

    const auto bspTreeOther(vtkSmartPointer<vtkModifiedBSPTree>::New());
    bspTreeOther->SetDataSet(meshDataOther);
    bspTreeOther->BuildLocator();

    double point1[3]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; // start of line segment used to intersect the model.
    double point2[3]{0.0, 0.0, 10.0}; // end of line segment
    double distanceAlongLine;
    double intersectionCoords[3]; // The coordinate of the intersection.
    double parametricCoords[3]; // Parametric Coordinates of the intersection - see https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/VTKBook/08Chapter8/#82-interpolation-functions
    int subId; // ?
    vtkIdType cellId;

    double intersectedTextureCoords[2];

    if (bspTreeOther->IntersectWithLine(point1, point2, TOLERANCE, distanceAlongLine, intersectionCoords, parametricCoords, subId, cellId))
    {
        const auto textureCoordsOther(meshDataOther->GetPointData()->GetTCoords());

        const auto pointIds{meshDataOther->GetCell(cellId)->GetPointIds()};

        const auto vertexIndex0{pointIds->GetId(0)};
        const auto vertexIndex1{pointIds->GetId(1)};
        const auto vertexIndex2{pointIds->GetId(2)};

        double texCoord0[2];
        double texCoord1[2];
        double texCoord2[2];
        textureCoordsOther->GetTuple(vertexIndex0, texCoord0);
        textureCoordsOther->GetTuple(vertexIndex1, texCoord1);
        textureCoordsOther->GetTuple(vertexIndex2, texCoord2);

        const auto parametricR{parametricCoords[0]};
        const auto parametricS{parametricCoords[1]};

        const auto barycentricW0{1 - parametricR - parametricS};
        const auto barycentricW1{parametricR};
        const auto barycentricW2{parametricS};

        intersectedTextureCoords[0] =
                barycentricW0 * texCoord0[0] +
                barycentricW1 * texCoord1[0] +
                barycentricW2 * texCoord2[0];
        intersectedTextureCoords[1] =
                barycentricW0 * texCoord0[1] +
                barycentricW1 * texCoord1[1] +
                barycentricW2 * texCoord2[1];
    }
```

Please note that this code is an interpretation of the actual code I'm using; I'm using Qt and its QVector2D and QVector3D classes along with some interpreter glue functions to go to and from arrays of doubles.

See https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/VTKBook/08Chapter8 for details about the parametric coordinate systems of various cell types.